# Unable to find object name in outline bar

Tags: object, join, export, alembic, alembic-format

I have been working on animating on animating a peacock. The error which is coming up while exporting alembic file format is as follows-
I have named two objects as 'joint One', however when I go to the outline bar, I am unable to find either objects named the  same. What could be the issue.
I am attaching file here for anyone to explore and guide me.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cZXc9gmijnqR-WNOi1obXg4CaxKllwSc/view?usp=sharing

Things I have tried:

1. Search in outline bar
2. Tried changing all names of the joints, yet no results.